# Cannot find the source of a large DATA column memory consumption for a Python program

Tags: python, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am developing a python application with a lot of my own packages and classes where the RAM constraint is really important. I am using the [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout) utility to monitor this constraint externally. To my surprise, my program fails silently at the very beginning if the VM limit is below 800MB.

To investigate, I used the psutil's [memory_info](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_info) to get more insight about what's happening. I have placed this method at the very beginning of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block (so, before any logic of the program is executed). Here is the result:
`pmem(rss=94330880, vms=792522752, shared=35758080, text=2834432, lib=0, data=650641408, dirty=0)`

So the `data` field is occupying 650MB at the very beginning of the program already! I thought that maybe the problem is with the imports at the top of the `main.py`, here is the input of `tracemalloc`:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:672: size=105 KiB, count=973, average=111 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/abc.py:106: size=4326 B, count=11, average=393 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/statistics.py:1051: size=2585 B, count=10, average=258 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/abc.py:107: size=2520 B, count=42, average=60 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/statistics.py:436: size=2352 B, count=2, average=1176 B
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:128: size=2339 B, count=17, average=138 B
/home/tatiana/Documents/project/utils/utils.py:6: size=1944 B, count=12, average=162 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/statistics.py:144: size=1928 B, count=10, average=193 B
/home/tatiana/Documents/project/package/Seed.py:5: size=1872 B, count=8, average=234 B
/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py:481: size=1835 B, count=8, average=229 B
```

So imports don't seem to be the problem. On a VM, after downloading the project from Github, I got the 250MB consumption for DATA field, which is fewer, but still seems unreasonably large. On both my machine and the VM I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

EDIT: so I have 2 goals right now:

1. Find out why the memory consumption of the program is so large and different for different measurement ways (this is where I am currently struggling and need help).
2. Reduce the memory usage in a way that the program can run with 800MB RAM available, better less (blocked by 1, but when 1 solved, can do this on my own)

Here is also the output of the python `memory_profiler` for the `main()` function:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    36     93.0 MiB     93.0 MiB           1   @profile
    37                                         def main():
    38     93.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       cli_args = read_cli()
    39                                         
    40     93.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       dataLoader = DataLoader(cli_args['src_1'], cli_args['seed_pool_size'])
    41     98.7 MiB      5.7 MiB           1       seeds = dataLoader.loadData()
    42                                         
    43     98.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       list_1 = []
    44     98.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       list_params = {'source_2': cli_args['src_2'], 'pool_size': cli_args['seed_pool_size'],
    45     98.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                          'percent_of_len': 1}
    46                                         
    47    106.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       for list_el in cli_args['list_els']:
    48     98.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           concreteEl = getattr(import_module("generator." + list_el), list_el)
    49    106.7 MiB      8.0 MiB           1           list_1.append(concreteEl(list_params))
    50                                         
    51    106.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       Strategy = getattr(import_module("generator.strategies." + cli_args['strategy']), cli_args['strategy'])
    52    106.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       strategy = Strategy(seeds, list_1, dataLoader)
    53                                         
    54    106.8 MiB      0.1 MiB           2       Features = getattr(import_module("featurefeeder.featuretypes." + cli_args['features']),
    55    106.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                          cli_args['features'])
    56    106.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       feature_extractor = Features()
    57                                         
    58    141.5 MiB     34.8 MiB           1       Model = getattr(import_module("dut.models." + cli_args['model']), cli_args['model'])
    59    142.0 MiB      0.4 MiB           1       model = Model(cli_args['model_src'])
    60                                         
    61    142.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       coverage = Coverage()
    62    142.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       monitor = Monitor(coverage, strategy)
    63                                         
    64    144.4 MiB      2.4 MiB           1       run(cli_args['epochs'], strategy, feature_extractor, model, coverage, monitor)
```

However, if I set the memory limit to 800MB, it fails, and the output of the timeout is the following:
`MEM CPU 2.78 MEM 807556 MAXMEM 807556 STALE 0 MAXMEM_RSS 121552`

So what is interesting for me here is why, even though the `memory_profiler` shows 144.4 MiB memory usage at the end of the last instruction of the `main()` function, the timeout still shows `MAXMEM 845748`? From the utility code, I found out that this is the virtual memory size in Linux, so I would suppose the difference comes from the fact that memory profiler only measures the physical RAM used ( =rss). And the next and the ultimate question is how can I reduce the virtual memory usage? First I checked for all the unused/wildcard imports, everything seems fine, and my next idea is heap allocations.

Any directions where to further investigate this problem would be highly appreciated!

Comment: in pycharm profile you can checkout the memory usages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to have a look at memory profiler
`pip install memory-profiler`